# Apply a function element-wise to two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

How to apply a function `z_ij = f(x_ij, y_ij)` from DataFrame `X` and `Y` of the same size and save the result to DataFrame `Z`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just in case someone finds themselves here like I did, there is a function that does this now for pandas!

```py
Z = X.combine(Y, lambda x, y: f(x, y))
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html

Comment: This combines 2 dataframes with a function. What If I have a function that takes as an argument more than 2 , is there a way to use this one or still need to use the np.vectorize ?

Comment: This is also not element wise it is column wise. Alas.

Comment: How do you mean? I don't think that is the case.

Comment: @AtanasAtanasov This way only works with 2. With certain simple functions, you could chain them together, but that won't generalize.

Answer (score 11):

It depends on what kind of function you have, a lot of functions have already been vectorized for data frame, such as `+-*/` etc, so for these functions, you can simply do `Z = X + Y` or `Z = X - Y` etc.

For a more general function, you can use `numpy.vectorize` to make a vectorized version of it and then apply to two data frames:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

X = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]])
Y = pd.DataFrame([[2,1], [3,3]])
​
def f(x, y):                      # this is a demo function that takes in two ints and 
    return str(x) + str(y)        # concatenate them as str
​
vecF = np.vectorize(f)            # vectorize the function with numpy.vectorize
​
X
#   0   1
#0  1   2
#1  3   4

Y
#   0   1
#0  2   1
#1  3   3

pd.DataFrame(vecF(X, Y))          # apply the function to two data frames

#    0   1
#0  12  21
#1  33  43
```

Comment: This is so beautiful! Would be nice to have this as a pandas function `pandas.elementwise_combine(left=X, right=Y, func=f)` that preserves columns and indices (given that `X` and `X` share the same indices/columns)