# Better way to create new pandas comparison dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance

I have three dataframes of the same size. I'm wondering if there's a more concise and/or efficient way to create a new dataframe again of the same size, whereby the values are set according to comparisons of the original dataframes. For example:

Original three dataframes: `close, low, high`

```
long_short = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(close)
long_short[:] = 0
long_short = long_short.astype(np.int64)
long_short[close < low] = -1
long_short[close > high] = 1
```

Comment: What does reindex_like() achieve on empty dataframe?

Comment: Just copying the size and header of the `close` df

Comment: You can vectorise a function of three dataframes to create a new df based on close, low, high as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277400/apply-a-function-element-wise-to-two-dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice to have a sample of the data to be sure.

How about just doing the comparison and then converting the booleans to 0/1 values?

```
negative_values = (close < low).astype(int)
positive_values = (close > high).astype(int)

long_short = positive_values - negative_values
```

Comment: Hmm thanks this would work how I stated the question although I actually got it wrong and `close` is a subset of the columns/indices in `low` and `high`

Comment: ok then it would be nice to get a sample of data to be sure
you can create a dataframe easily with something like:

>>> pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[4,4,5]})
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  4
2  3  5

Comment: Oops I was right the first time they are the same size (just had a typo that was confusing me) thanks your solution works well